# Python csv writer always skips last 15-30 lines

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file, in every line I have a random amount of integers (atleast 1) which could possibly be all 0, separated by a comma.
But the last 15-30 (different everytime I run it, data is always same length) lines are not saved. I even added a counter to check how far the loop goes and the counter reaches the correct value.
This is the code of the writer:

```
writer = csv.writer(open("one_hot_encoded.csv", 'w'))
counter=0
for row in data:
    counter+=1
    writer.writerow([counter,row])
print(counter)
```

This is an example for a line in the csv file:

57732,"[0, 1232, 3570, 4654, 4154, 8555, 0]"

Comment: You aren't closing the file, so the final bufferfull of data is not being flushed to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Your application is probably dying an horrible death, due to the way it is launched, instead of shutting down normally.

That prevents Python from flushing the files contents.

Just open the file using a context-manager block (the "with" command) to prevent this from happening:

```
with open("one_hot_encoded.csv", 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    counter=0
    for row in data:
        counter+=1
        writer.writerow([counter,row])
print(counter)
```

Context managers, such as used by the `with` statement ensure that resources are properly terminated once the block is over. One of the more common resources, and usually shown up as examples of how to use the `with` command are exactly files.
The end of the block makes Python call underneath the `__exit__` method on the file, which in turn will close the file. You can also do it explicitly by calling `file.close()` and do not use the `with` block.

Usually Python processes will delete objects when terminating, and this process cause all open files to be closed - but that is not guarranteed to happen, and due to some reason, it is what is happening in your original code.

If you prefer to call `.close` you can do as follows:

```
writer = csv.writer(file:=open("one_hot_encoded.csv", 'w'))
counter=0
for row in data:
    counter+=1
    writer.writerow([counter,row])
file.close()
print(counter)
```

Note the "walrus operator"(`:=`) assigning the open file to the "file" variable just before the resulting object is passed as an argument to the `csv.writer`.

Comment: Thank you very much for that detailed answer! That fixed it and I also learned something about context managers.